# How do UIPath selectors work when there is no specific ID

Tags: uipath

I am trying to create a UIPath project to automate filling out a simple form in Microsoft Dynamics Web Client 2016. I have been running into problems with strange behavior due to what I believe to be unreliable selectors. The Dynamics web client is written with Angular and seems to be a single page application. None of the inputs have any type of ID or specific data-attribute that UIPath can use as a selector as far as I can tell. It looks like the program is using the DOM tree to count the number of nested divs in order to assign each input with a "parentId" attribute. This seems to cause unreliable behavior when there are popup windows and I am worried that going forward with an automation with this particular web application will not be scalable.

Example of a selector:

```
<html title="Microsoft Dynamics GP" />
<webctrl parentid='a000000000000000056800083584c00030100000000f1550000000000'
tag='INPUT' />
```

Where are this selector and parentId attribute coming from and will it be reliable and scalable through updates and form changes?

[image: Example of selector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the element itself can't be found reliably, just work around the issue by using an anchor on an element that can. For example, the `input` elements on http://www.rpachallenge.com/ can never be found reliably as their id changes every few minutes. So, if you need to type text into the field for "Company Name", we need to work with anchors - in our case there will always be a label with a distinctive text.

[image: relative selector with anchor]

You will need to use an [Anchor Base](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/anchor-base) along with a [Find Element](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/wait-ui-element-appear) activity (plus the desired action). Here's the selector for the anchor - using the element's descriptive text:

```
<webctrl aaname='Company Name' tag='LABEL' />
```

Then, the `Type Into` activity just refers to an `Input` element:

```
<webctrl tag='INPUT' />
```

The only thing to keep in mind are multiple languages in which case you will need to either consider them in the selector, or select the element by id, if applicable.

Comment: The only problem is that this application does not even have label text available. It is all buried in Angular javascript objects. None of it is accessible in HTML, so the RPA challenge example does not work without settling with Citrix/image-based automation. I will accept your answer as it seems like the best answer that UIPath can offer, but it still does not create a rock solid automation in this particular Angular app, in my opinion. It really feels like if the selectors are no good, using UI automation is like building a house of cards that will eventually fail after any updates.

Comment: Judging from the first screenshot, some elements seem to have ids (e.g. gpContentArea). I agree that finding reliable selectors is the main challenge, and I am wondering if you could provide the whole (relevant) HTML as an example. Note that UiPath inserts alters the HTML by inserting attributes, so saving the page as HTML in your browser would do just fine. I will gladly have another look.

Comment: That id is the wrapper for the entire page, nothing inside of the form has any sort of identifiable IDs or data-attributes. We have already scoured the UI Explorer and spoke with a UIPath engineer about the issue. The automation is working right now, I am just concerned that it will need to be tweaked if future updates include any UI changes. I am just a bit cynical about UI automation when the selectors are no good. It seems like Angular best practices should include adding IDs to inputs, even if Angular doesn't need them, in order to support stuff like UI automation.

Comment: Have you compared what the browser sees to what Ui Explorer is displaying? I've had the odd site not display all the available attributes when viewed in Ui Explorer (Haven't tried an Angular site specifically) requiring you to type in the attribute name and value manually... OCR would be another option. But as you allude I don't believe RPA is the solution for cases where the site/application are constantly changing where you have no control on development cycle or if its not well designed for  RPA and other accessibility options.